# Compute $I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{8}{\gamma^{4}} x^{3} e^{-\frac{2}{\gamma^{2}}x^{2}} e^{jxt} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

I want to evaluate the following integral:

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{8}{\gamma^{4}} x^{3} e^{-\frac{2}{\gamma^{2}}x^{2}} e^{jxt} dx $$

Where $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $j = \sqrt{-1}$.

---

The first thing I do is let:

$$ u = \frac{2}{\gamma} x  \quad \Rightarrow  \quad  du = \frac{2}{\gamma} dx$$
$$ x = \frac{\gamma}{2} u  \quad \Rightarrow  \quad  dx = \frac{\gamma}{2} du$$

After substituting and cancellation, we get:

$$ I = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} u^{2} + j \frac{1}{2} \gamma tu} du$$

We complete the square, giving:

$$ I = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (u - j\frac{1}{2} \gamma t)^{2} - \frac{1}{8} \gamma^{2} t^{2}} du$$
$$ I = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{8} \gamma^{2} t^{2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (u - j\frac{1}{2} \gamma t)^{2}} du$$

This is where I am unsure of what to do. My approach is as follows:

---

We want to solve:

$$ I = \frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{8} \gamma^{2} t^{2}} \underset{R \rightarrow \infty}{lim}  \int_{0}^{R} u^{3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (u - j\frac{1}{2} \gamma t)^{2}} du$$

We let:

$$ z = u - j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t  \quad \Rightarrow  \quad  dy = du$$
$$ u = y + j\frac{1}{2} \gamma t  \quad \Rightarrow  \quad  du = dy$$
$$ b = R - j\frac{1}{2} \gamma t \quad a = -j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t $$

Therefore:

$$ I = \frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{8} \gamma^{2} t^{2}} \underset{R \rightarrow \infty}{lim}  \int_{ -j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t}^{R - j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t} (y- j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t)^{3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^{2}} dy$$

We create a contour $\Gamma = C_{1} + C_{2} + C_{3} + C_{4} = [-j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t, R-j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t] + [R-j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t, R] + [R, 0] + [0, -j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t]$

Since $ \underset{y \rightarrow \infty}{lim}\frac{(y - j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t)^{3}}{e^{\frac{1}{2}y^{2}}} = 0  $, the integral over the vertical contour $C_{3}$ is zero.

However I still need to evaluate the following integrals:

$$ I_{1} = \underset{R \rightarrow \infty}{lim}  \int_{0}^{R} (y- j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t)^{3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^{2}} dy $$
$$ I_{2} = \int_{-j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t}^{0} (y- j \frac{1}{2} \gamma t)^{3} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^{2}} dy $$

This is where I am getting stuck.

---

Is this the right approach? Am I on the right track? How can I solve those two integrals? How can I solve my original problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in general we have:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}:=\int_0^{\infty}x^\text{n}\cdot\exp\left(\alpha \cdot x^{\text{n}-1}\right)\cdot\exp\left(\beta\cdot x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Using the '[evaluating integrals over the positive real axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis)' property of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{L}_x\left[\exp\left(\alpha \cdot x^{\text{n}-1}\right)\cdot\exp\left(\beta\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\cdot\mathcal{L}_x^{-1}\left[x^\text{n}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\space\text{ds}\tag2$$

Using the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the Laplace transform:

- $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[\exp\left(\alpha \cdot x^{\text{n}-1}\right)\cdot\exp\left(\beta\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\mathcal{L}_x\left[\exp\left(\alpha \cdot x^{\text{n}-1}\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}-\beta\right)}\tag3$$
- $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[\exp\left(\alpha \cdot x^{\text{n}-1}\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}-\beta\right)}=\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\mathcal{L}_x\left[x^{\text{k}\left(\text{n}-1\right)}\right]_{\left(\text{s}-\beta\right)}=\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\text{k}\left(\text{n}-1\right)\right)}{\left(\text{s}-\beta\right)^{1+\text{k}\left(\text{n}-1\right)}}\tag4$$
- $$\mathcal{L}_x^{-1}\left[x^\text{n}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{s}^{1+\text{n}}}\tag5$$

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\int_0^\infty\left\{\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\text{k}\left(\text{n}-1\right)\right)}{\left(\text{s}-\beta\right)^{1+\text{k}\left(\text{n}-1\right)}}\right\}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{s}^{1+\text{n}}}\space\text{ds}=$$
$$\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\text{k}\left(\text{n}-1\right)\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\text{n}\right)}\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{\text{s}^{-1-\text{n}}}{\left(\text{s}-\beta\right)^{1+\text{k}\left(\text{n}-1\right)}}\space\text{ds}\tag6$$

Using the property:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\text{m}}{\left(x-t\right)^\text{p}}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\left(-t\right)^{\text{p}-1-\text{m}}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\text{m}\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(\text{p}-\text{m}-1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\text{p}\right)}\tag7$$

Gives:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\left(-1\right)^{\text{k}-\text{n}\left(1+\text{k}\right)-1}\cdot\beta^{\text{k}-\text{n}\left(1+\text{k}\right)-1}\cdot\Gamma\left(1+\text{k}\left(\text{n}-1\right)+\text{n}\right)\tag8$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find $$\int_0^\infty e^{-2 x^2/\gamma^2} e^{jxt}\; dx $$
and differentiate $3$ times with respect to $t$.

Comment: Okay, but I am not sure how this is going to help haha. So I need to find this integral first, THEN differentiate three times with respect to t?

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7#E3

Comment: @KBDave That is 2jt though while I only have jt...

Comment: lump in the $2$ with the free variable

Comment: @KBDave Of course...haha. I need to eat lunch haha Then take a look at this F function, and figure out how to do the differentiation. Hmmm...